# How to plot the graphics in the wolfram blog?

Tags: plotting

As the image style in this [blog](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2022/12/the-latest-from-our-rd-pipeline-version-13-2-of-wolfram-language-mathematica/):
[image]

I think it's a graphics drawn using *MMA* code, but how to use *MMA* to know the release time of each version to plot it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `TimeLinePlot` with the data from [Daniel Huber's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/285703/125):

```
releasedates = SortBy[Last][
   StringReplace["Mathematica " -> ""]@# -> AbsoluteTime[#2] & @@@ rdDHuber];

split = SplitBy[releasedates, First@StringSplit[First@#, "."] &];

stitched = Partition[
  Extract[Values[#][[{1, -1}]] & /@ split, {{All, 1}, {-1, -1}}, 
     Apply[Sequence]], 2, 1]

 
tlp1 = TimelinePlot[List /@ (DateInterval /@ stitched), 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", AxesOrigin -> 0, Spacings -> 1, 
   Filling -> Below, ImageSize -> 1200];

tlp2 = TimelinePlot[Map[Labeled[#[[2]], #[[1]], Above] &] /@ split, 
   PlotLayout -> "Overlapped", Spacings -> 1, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"];

postProcess = ReplaceAll[
   Text[t_, Offset[{0, y_}, c_], d_] :> 
    {Text[t, Offset[{0, y + 30}, c], {0, 0}, {0, 1}],  
     Line[{Offset[{0, y + 3}, c], Offset[{0, y + 15}, c]}], White, 
     Line[{Offset[{0, -y}, c], Offset[{0, -y - 50}, c]}]}];

zoom = AbsoluteTime /@ {{2014, 1}, {2023, 1}}; 

Column[{Show[tlp1, postProcess@tlp2, 
  Prolog -> 
   {AbsoluteThickness[10], Orange, CapForm["Round"], Line[Thread[{zoom, 0}]]}],
 Show[tlp1, postProcess@tlp2, PlotRange -> {zoom, {8, All}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: `WolframLanguageData[All,{"FullVersionIntroduced","DateIntroduced"}]//Tally` too can get all date

Answer (score 5):

The release dates can be see on the Internet page:

```
url = "https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history/";
```

It is not very difficult to get this page into MMA:

```
dat = URLRead[url, "Body"];
```

This is now a hugh string and the difficult task is to dissect this string. Regular expression is your friend here:

```
regex= RegularExpression["(Mathematica \\d+(\\.\\d+)+)</span>.*(\r\n.*){2}\r\n.*</span>(\\w+ \\d+)"]
```

With this we can extract the needed information from the string:

```
 StringCases[dat,regex :> {"$1", "$4"}]

{{"Mathematica 13.2.1", "February 2023"}, {"Mathematica 13.2", 
  "December 2022"}, {"Mathematica 13.1", 
  "June 2022"}, {"Mathematica 13.0.1", 
  "February 2022"}, {"Mathematica 12.3.1", 
  "July 2021"}, {"Mathematica 12.3", "May 2021"}, {"Mathematica 12.2",
   "December 2020"}, {"Mathematica 12.1.1", 
  "June 2020"}, {"Mathematica 12.1", 
  "March 2020"}, {"Mathematica 11.3", 
  "March 2018"}, {"Mathematica 11.2", 
  "September 2017"}, {"Mathematica 11.1.1", 
  "April 2017"}, {"Mathematica 11.1", 
  "March 2017"}, {"Mathematica 11.0.1", 
  "September 2016"}, {"Mathematica 10.4.1", 
  "April 2016"}, {"Mathematica 10.4", 
  "March 2016"}, {"Mathematica 10.3.1", 
  "December 2015"}, {"Mathematica 10.3", 
  "October 2015"}, {"Mathematica 10.2", 
  "July 2015"}, {"Mathematica 10.1", 
  "March 2015"}, {"Mathematica 10.0.2", 
  "December 2014"}, {"Mathematica 10.0.1", 
  "September 2014"}, {"Mathematica 10.0.0", 
  "July 2014"}, {"Mathematica 9.0.1", 
  "January 2013"}, {"Mathematica 9.0.0", 
  "November 2012"}, {"Mathematica 8.0.4", 
  "October 2011"}, {"Mathematica 8.0.1", 
  "March 2011"}, {"Mathematica 8.0", 
  "November 2010"}, {"Mathematica 7.0.1", 
  "March 2009"}, {"Mathematica 7.0", 
  "November 2008"}, {"Mathematica 6.0.3", 
  "June 2008"}, {"Mathematica 6.0.2", 
  "February 2008"}, {"Mathematica 6.0.1", 
  "July 2007"}, {"Mathematica 6.0", "May 2007"}, {"Mathematica 5.2", 
  "July 2005"}, {"Mathematica 5.1", 
  "November 2004"}, {"Mathematica 5.0", 
  "June 2003"}, {"Mathematica 4.2", "June 2002"}, {"Mathematica 4.1", 
  "November 2000"}, {"Mathematica 4.0", 
  "May 1999"}, {"Mathematica 3.0", 
  "September 1996"}, {"Mathematica 2.2", 
  "June 1993"}, {"Mathematica 2.1", "June 1992"}, {"Mathematica 2.0", 
  "January 1991"}, {"Mathematica 1.2", 
  "August 1989"}, {"Mathematica 1.0", "June 1988"}}
```